# How to do a post request for my reCaptcha ajax api?

Tags: php, ajax, http, codeigniter, recaptcha

My reCaptcha is now implemented into my signup process using ajax..

Currently no matter what is typed in the captcha text field it never validates. It just keeps giving me new words to type in.

I've figured it's because I need to test if the user entered the right captcha answer. I need to send a POST request.

I have no idea how to do this.. I've never had to do this before and the documentation isn't clear enough for me..

I would appreciate any help I could get.

Here my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#fhjoinForm').submit(function(e) {

        register();
        e.preventDefault();

    });

});


function register()
{
    hideshow('loading',1);
    error(0);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: $('#fhjoinForm').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg){

                if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
                {
                Recaptcha.create("pub key xxxxxxxxxxx",
               "recaptcha_div",
                {
                theme: "clean",
                callback: function(){
                // what to do on success
                window.location=msg.txt;
         }

            }

     );
   }

            else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0)
            {
                error(1,msg.txt);
            }

            hideshow('loading',0);
        }
    });

}


function hideshow(el,act)
{
    if(act) $('#'+el).css('visibility','visible');
    else $('#'+el).css('visibility','hidden');
}

function error(act,txt)
{
    hideshow('error',act);
    if(txt) $('#error').html(txt);
}
```

This is for my post request

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "pub key hidden"; // you got this from the signup page
$privatekey = "priv key hidden";

$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if ($resp->is_valid) {
    ?>success<?
}
else 
{
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
       "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
}
?>
```

Comment: Hard to help without seeing any of your code. What javascript library do you use?

Comment: I use jquery. I'm going to post my code now.

Comment: I'm following these instructions: http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html and it wants me to add a URL to my form action which already has "submit.php" there. Submit.php contains all my server side validation rules for my form and with out that the ajax won't work. So how do I get around this. The reCaptcha library is in place. I just need to some how edit that javascript code so that after successful form validation captcha pops up or shows up and hides fields then when that is successfully passed my form is then submitted.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the submit.php can be called from within the verify.php file? It can be called upon if validation of captcha is passed? just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code looks like it's creating the reCAPTCHA after the form is submitted, because it's creating it in the success() function after PHP has tried to validate.  But really, the reCAPTCHA should be created and displayed first.

Then on the form submit run register and let PHP check the value.

1. Display reCAPTCHA and wait for user to submit
2. Send AJAX to PHP and let recaptcha_check_answer do it's job
3. Display the error or success to the user.

Comment: That makes more sense. It could be like the last validation process straight after the field validation. Would you be able to give me a code example?

Comment: Actually I think it's right the way it is. If validation is passed e.g. if(parseInt(msg.status)==1) that would mean all fields didn't get an error "0" and passed validation.. then it would redirect to the 'registered.html' page. So instead of that forwarding I want the captcha to come up let the user verify and pass before it goes on to the redirecting part of the code.