# Posting with form with using recaptcha

Tags: php, jquery, recaptcha

I have a simple form

```
<form id="myform" action="formprocess.php" method="POST">
username:<input type="text" name="username">
password:<input type="password" name="password">
<?php if($_COOKIE("login-attempt")>"4"){
require_once "recaptchalib.php";
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
}?>
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" id="signIn" name="signIn""/>
</form>
```

the problem is that is captcha(recaptcha_response_field) is also posted to formprocess.php page, I want that this captcha(recaptcha_response_field) value should be checked here if it is right than the value of username and password should be posed to formprocess.php else reload this page with the error. how can i do this.?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest thing to do in my eyes would be to validate the CAPTCHA at the beginning of `formprocess.php`, and if it wouldn't work then `die('CAPTCHA failed)`, otherwise run the script. I.E:

```
function verifyCAPTCHA(){
  //function that verifies the captcha...
}
if (!verifyCaptcha()){
  die('CAPTCHA Failed')
}
//the rest of your formprocess.php
```

But, if you insist on seperating `formprocess.php` from the CAPTCHA validation, then you can instead change the form `action` attribute to something like `action='captchaValidate.php'`.

`captchaValidate.php` would then look like:

```
function verifyCAPTCHA(){
  //function that verifies the captcha...
}
if (!verifyCaptcha()){
  die('CAPTCHA Failed')
}else{
  require('formprocess.php')
}
```

When you say you'd like to validate the CAPTCHA 'here', perhaps you mean to say that you'd like to send an AJAX request, in which you should check out https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display and their AJAX API. You could dynamically call either one of my proposed solutions this way. Also take a look at [How to do a post request for my reCaptcha ajax api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764633/how-to-do-a-post-request-for-my-recaptcha-ajax-api)

Comment: i have one more problem ....what if user has disabled the java script....in that case recaptcha will work but ajax will not work....

Comment: Short version: make the AJAX work within a regular `form` with the action and all that properly set. Then make a submit button which triggers a javascript function that `returns false` and executes your AJAX. If javascript is disabled, the form will just submit the data to the file at the action.

This article explains it quite nicely http://phpnoob.blogspot.ca/2006/06/making-ajax-web-forms-degrade.html.

Comment: that explains nothing it also says that if java script is disabled than form will work normal...what will we do in that case..